# Python Hashing of "tupled" numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, hash

I have a class `MyClass` where each instance stores pixels' x- and y-coordinates, represented as two 1D numpy arrays (of the same length). Two instances are considered equal if their coordinate arrays are identical (including `nan`).
I tried two methods of hashing: one by casting both arrays to tuples and hashing those, and the other by calling the `tobytes()` method for each array:

```
class MyClass:
  # ... init, doA(), doB(), etc. ...
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if not type(self) == type(other):
      return False
    if not np.array_equal(self._x, other._x, equal_nan=True):
      return False
    if not np.array_equal(self._y, other._y, equal_nan=True):
      return False
    return True

  def hash1(self):
    return hash((tuple(self._x), tuple(self._y)))

  def hash2(self):
    return hash((self._x.tobytes(), self._y.tobytes()))
```

Calling `hash1` on the same instance yields different hashes, and calling `hash2` outputs the same thing every time. Why do these behave so differently?

Comment: Is there a practical reason why you wouldn't store the pixels as a single 2D array?

Comment: "Two instances are considered equal if their coordinate arrays are identical (including nan)." - nans don't hash consistently.

Comment: Every time you call `tuple`, you get new element wrapper objects. Two different element wrappers for NaN elements don't have to hash the same.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this by hashing a tuple of bytes objects derived from NumPy. Each time I run the hash function, I get the same hash. Can you include an array that triggers this problem?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this is likely due to the fact that my arrays contain `nan` values. @NickODell try reproducing with an array containing nans.
@AKX no, not a particular practical reason. that's just how I chose to implement my class. Does this have any relevance to my question?

Comment: @JonNir I am trying an array containing NaN values. Here's my reproduction code: https://gist.github.com/nickodell/e5ab60f76cb5e0f4ae61af8ec113c6e3

Comment: as mentioned, when using `x.tobytes()` the hash is stable, but when using `tuple(x)` hashing is inconsistent. see `hash1` in my code snippet above, @NickODell

Comment: @user2357112 can you please elaborate? what are "element wrapper objects"?
If you write this as an answer I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NumPy array doesn't store its elements as Python objects (unless you're using dtype=object). It stores raw hardware numeric values. That means when you call `tuple`, the array has to *create* Python objects for all the elements. For example, if your array has dtype float64, the array has to generate instances of `numpy.float64`.

The array doesn't save these wrapper objects. Every time you call `tuple`, the array generates new wrapper objects. Two instances of `numpy.float64` with NaN values aren't guaranteed to hash the same, so if your array contains NaNs, hashing the tuples isn't guaranteed to produce consistent results.